No puedo agregar los items al incio unshift java script
hola reformulo la pregunta ya que en la otra puse el codigo extenso, no puedo agregar los productos al inicio en mi tabla, por unshift, si los ordena por ID pero yo quiero que los vaya agregando al incio cada que se escriben.
si perdon, coloco todo el codigo y la tabla donde los valores se van agregando.
he conseguido ordenarlos, pero no consigo que se agreguen al principio o al final.
e.unshift(spositems);  uso este valor y este
spositems.unshift(t);  pero no consigo que se agreguen al inicio
function add_invoice_item(t) {
if (1 == count && (spositems = {}), null != t) {
    var e = 1 == Settings.item_addition ? t.item_id : t.id;
    return spositems[e] ? spositems[e].row.qty = parseFloat(spositems[e].row.qty) + 1 : spositems[e] = t, store("spositems", JSON.stringify(spositems)), loadItems(), !0
        e.unshift(spositems);       
} } 


function loadItems() {
if (1 == count && (spositems = {}), get("spositems")) {
    total = 0, count = 1, an = 1, product_tax = 0, invoice_tax = 0, product_discount = 0, order_discount = 0, total_discount = 0, $("#posTable tbody").empty();
    
    var t = (new Date).getTime() / 1e3;
    if (1 != Settings.remote_printing) {
        var e = (r = "C: " + $("#select2-spos_customer-container").text() + "\n") + (i = "R: " + $("#hold_ref").val() + "\n") + (l = "U: " + username + "\n") + (c = "T: " + date(Settings.dateformat + " " + Settings.timeformat, t) + "\n") + "\n";
        order_data.info = e, bill_data.info = e;
        var a = "",
            o = ""
    } else {
        $("#order_span").empty(), $("#bill_span").empty();
        
        var n = "<style>.bb td, .bb th { border-bottom: 1px solid #DDD; }</style>",
            s = '<span style="text-align:center;"><h3>' + Settings.site_name + "</h3>",
            r = "<h5>C: " + $("#select2-spos_customer-container").text() + "</h5>",
            i = "<h5>R: " + $("#hold_ref").val() + "</h5>",
            l = "<h5>U: " + username + "</h5>",
            c = "<h5>T: " + date(Settings.dateformat + " " + Settings.timeformat, t) + "</h5>";
        $("#order_span").prepend(n + s + "<h4>" + lang.order + "</h4></span>" + r + i + l + c), $("#bill_span").prepend(n + s + "<h4>" + lang.bill + "</h4></span>" + r + i + l + c), $("#order-table").empty(), $("#bill-table").empty()
    }
     

spositems = JSON.parse(get("spositems")), $.each(spositems, function() {
            
        var t = this,
        e = 1 == Settings.item_addition ? t.item_id : t.id;     
        spositems[e] = t;   

        var n = t.row.id,
            s = t.row.type,
            r = parseFloat(t.row.tax_method),
            i = t.combo_items,
            l = t.row.qty,
            c = parseFloat(t.row.quantity),
            h = t.row.quantity,
            s = t.row.type,
            d = t.row.discount,
            p = t.row.code,
            u = t.row.name.replace(/"/g, "&#034;").replace(/'/g, "&#039;"),
            m = parseFloat(t.row.real_unit_price),
            _ = t.row.comment,
            g = t.row.ordered ? t.row.ordered : 0,
            f = d || "0",
            v = formatDecimal(f);               
        if (-1 !== f.indexOf("%")) {
            var h = f.split("%");
            isNaN(h[0]) || (v = formatDecimal(parseFloat(m * parseFloat(h[0]) / 100), 4))

        }

k = $('<tr id="' + x + '" class="' + e + '" data-item-id="' + e + '" data-id="' + t.row.id + '"></tr>'); 
        tr_html = '<td><input name="product_id[]" type="hidden" class="rid" value="' + n + '"><input name="item_comment[]" type="hidden" class="ritem_comment" value="' + _ + '"><input name="product_code[]" type="hidden" value="' + t.row.code + '"><input name="product_name[]" type="hidden" value="' + t.row.name + '"><button type="button" class="btn bg-purple btn-block btn-xs edit" id="' + x + '" data-item="' + e + '"><span class="sname" id="name_' + x + '">' + u + " (" + p + ")</span></button></td>", 
        tr_html += '<td class="text-right"><input class="realuprice" name="real_unit_price[]" type="hidden" value="' + t.row.real_unit_price + '"><input class="rdiscount" name="product_discount[]" type="hidden" id="discount_' + x + '" value="' + f + '"><span class="text-right sprice" id="sprice_' + x + '">' + formatMoney(parseFloat(m) + parseFloat(b)) + "</span></td>", 
        tr_html += '<td><input name="item_was_ordered[]" type="hidden" class="riwo" value="' + g + '"><input class="form-control input-qty kb-pad text-center rquantity" name="quantity[]" type="text" value="' + formatDecimal(l) + '" data-id="' + x + '" data-item="' + e + '" id="quantity_' + x + '" onClick="this.select();"></td>', 
        tr_html += '<td class="text-right"><span class="text-right ssubtotal" id="subtotal_' + x + '">' + formatMoney((parseFloat(m) + parseFloat(b)) * parseFloat(l)) + "</span></td>",
        tr_html += '<td class="text-right"><span class="text-right ccantidade" id="cantidade_' + x + '">' + formatDecimal((parseFloat(c) - parseFloat(l)), 2) + "</span></td>",
         tr_html += '<td class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-trash-o tip pointer posdel" id="' + x + '" title="Remove"></i></td>', 
         k.html(tr_html), k.prependTo("#posTable"), 


Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.
